# Travel from India, but visa Issued in Qatar for Schengen Poland single entry

Tags: schengen

I have a business travel from Doha to poland next week but I have some changes in my plans as now I am thinking of going to India first and travel from there to Poland. Will there be any issues as while applying the visa I had showed the tickets from Doha to Warsaw to Krakow.now I am planning bangalore to poland and back to bangalore single entry its just 7 days trip and confirmed hotel booking. Please advise.
Thanks Robin

Answer (score 2):

No, it should not be an issue, countries do not care where you come from.

The important things are that:

- You stay within the dates of validity of the visa
- The duration of your stay is similar to what you originally indicated, and of course within the limit set by the visa
- The reason for your stay remains the same, at least remains in the scope of the visa.
- You do have a flight out of the Schengen Area booked